# Make new document in TextMate with rb-appscript or AppleScript?

Tags: ruby, applescript, textmate, rb-appscript

How do I make a new document in TextMate using rb-appscript or AppleScript?

Here is my rb-appscript:

```
te = app("TextMate")
te.launch
doc = te.make(:new => :document)
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is the error message I get:

```
    OSERROR: -10000
    MESSAGE: Apple event handler failed.
    COMMAND: app("/Applications/TextMate.app").make({:new=>:document})
```

If someone gives me an AppleScript code I can convert it to rb-appscript.

Comment: thought the two of you might be interested in this http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=98A3E754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it's supposed to be just this:

```
tell application "TextMate"
    set theResult to make new document
end tell
```

But I get the same error in Script Debugger. Creating a new document manually and getting the document via a script works fine. I'm going to say you found a bug in TextMate's Applescript implementation. You could go the GUI scripting route here [(shamelessly copied from the Mac OS Automation site](http://www.macosautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html)):

```
return do_menu("TextMate", "File", "New")
--> result: true and a window appeared in TextMate

on do_menu(app_name, menu_name, menu_item)
    try
        -- bring the target application to the front
        tell application app_name
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process app_name
                tell menu bar 1
                    tell menu bar item menu_name
                        tell menu menu_name
                            click menu item menu_item
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        return true
    on error error_message
        return false
    end try
end do_menu
```